# Exclude items from part of checkbox list before sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-ui-sortable

Can't believe I'm stuck on this! 
The JS fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/27a8qypq/  shows countries appearing, in alphabetical order, from any combination of the 3 regional checkbox selections.
In the future I will want to restrict the scope of the country list using an instruction in the JS code.  For example, even with all 3 checkboxes ticked, I might want the code to exclude all Asian countries from appearing, but maintain the alphabetical order for the remaining countries being shown.
I've tried using .filter() and .detach() and .remove(), as suggested in previous posts, but am unable to get anything to work.

Can anyone suggest how I can add a small modification to the JS code so I can exclude the countries from 1 or 2 regions from being displayed?  Ideally I don't want to restructure the HTML.
Thanks

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="Europe" />Europe</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="Africa" />Africa</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="Asia" />Asia</label>


<div class="mywrapper">

<label class="myEurope">
<input type="checkbox" value="Spain" />Spain</label>
<label class="myEurope">
<input type="checkbox" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
<label class="myEurope">
<input type="checkbox" value="Austria" />Austria</label>

<label class="myAfrica">
<input type="checkbox" value="Nigeria" />Nigeria</label>
<label class="myAfrica">
<input type="checkbox" value="Egypt" />Egypt</label>
<label class="myAfrica">
<input type="checkbox" value="Kenya" />Kenya</label>

<label class="myAsia">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Thailand" />Thailand</label>
<label class="myAsia">
  <input type="checkbox" value="China" />China</label>
<label class="myAsia">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Japan" />Japan</label>

</div>





function sortByText(a, b) {
return $.trim($(a).text()) > $.trim($(b).text());
}

var li = $(".mywrapper").children("label").detach().sort(sortByText)
$(".mywrapper").append(li)

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
$('.my' + $(this).attr("id")).slideToggle(200)
})




.mywrapper {
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

.myEurope {
display: none;
}

.myAfrica {
display: none;
}

.myAsia {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've fully understood your question, but I purpose something. Just add the `disabled` property to all checkbox you don't want to have in your results, and modify your js with this ([JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/49dde8su/1/), I've disabled Spain for the example) :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $('.my' + $(this).attr("id") + " > input:enabled").each(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough.  What I want to do is disabIe a whole region, thereby disabling all the countries within it.  I'd rather not modify the HTML with the disabled property.  Is there not a way of modifying the jquery on the line where it sorts the list in ".mywrapper"  (starts var li = ...) so that it can exclude say, 'Asia'.  Alternatively, is there a command that can hide all the Asian countries on the last line of the jquery?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  All I needed to do was to add .removeClass(class name) just before .slideToggle(0); on the jQuery.   So if I want to exclude countries in class "myAsia" my jQuery is adjusted as follows:

```
function sortByText(a, b) {
return $.trim($(a).text()) > $.trim($(b).text());
}

var li = $(".mywrapper").children("label").detach().sort(sortByText)
$(".mywrapper").append(li)

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
$('.my' + $(this).attr("id")).removeClass("myAsia").slideToggle(200)
})
```